# XML: root element is missing

Tags: asp.net, xml, azure

I have this code to provision an instance in Azure via REST API. Last time I check it was running and no error, but when I reopen and redebug this morning, Exception suddenly rise up. rootElement is missing. But when I tried to put rootElement in my xml,still doesnt work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootElement>
...
</rootElement>
```

I check the location of my xml if it was correctly assigned. Nothing seems wrong. But giving me this error. What could be the cause of this problem

```
string myURL = "https://management.core.windows.net/mySubscriptionID/services/hostedservices/CloudService/deployments";
    string postBodyFileName = @"C:\Users\CompName\Desktop\REST API\VM-CreateVM.xml";
    string subscriptionID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Subscription"];
    string certificatePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePath"];
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri requestUri = new Uri(myURL);

        // Create the request and specify attributes of the request.
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);

        // Define the required headers to specify the API version and operation type.
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-03-01");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(postBodyFileName);

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
        xDoc.Save(streamWriter);
        streamWriter.Close();
        requestStream.Close();

        X509Certificate2 myCert = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath);
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(myCert);

        // Make the call using the web request.
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        HttpStatusCode responseStatus = response.StatusCode;
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        XmlDocument xDocResp = new XmlDocument();
        xDocResp.Load(reader);

        string operationsResponse = xDocResp.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name()='Operation' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure']/*[local-name()='Status' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure']").InnerXml;

    }
```

Comment: Looks like you don't setup `ContentLength` of the `request` object.

Comment: I dont think that is the reason, I look this code http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Windows-Azure-REST-b8200322 and he didnt assign ContentLength, I also tried to download this project and modified it based on my credentials still gave me the same error, root xml. hmmm

Comment: What happens if you simply try setting `ContentLength`?

Comment: im afraid it still the same error.

Comment: How do you compute the value to which you set `ContentLength`? Could you just include that into your code sample so that it's clear that the problem is elsewhere?